How to temporarily attach/adhere oak boxes to painted cinder block wall?
I have a large lot of 42"x13"13" oak planter boxes.  I want to eventually use them in a greenhouse I have not yet built. I would like to temporarily use them as bookshelves attached to a cinder block wall that's around 14' high until I'm ready to use them (it could be a while).  I'm hoping to find a way to adhere them together and to the wall without damaging the boxes too much when it comes time to separate them and move them into my future greenhouse.  The wall is painted.  The boxes are smooth and are not painted. Any advice on what to use or if this is even possible would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Screws are reversible. Modern adhesives mostly aren't. Connection to wall maybe optional if you will never have anything in the house tempted to try climbing them.

Books are heavy. Paint is flimsy. Even cinder block is not very strong in tension. Is it worth the trouble to make a temporary book shelf that could easily break and collapse. BTW, I have been (mildly ;-) traumatized when a bookshelf, held to a wall with toggle bolts. collapsed on my bed while I slept therein. (No real harm done, though.)

Define "temporary". Temporary buildings created in WWII are still in use...
